# Create a collection from collections?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I get two collections:

```
$user = User::all();
$access = Access::all();
```

I wish to pass these to a view in one data collection.

I've tried this:

```
$data = collect($user, $access);
```

With no luck. I want to access each collection in the view like:

```
$data->user->name;
```

Comment: Have you tried `$data = collect([$user, $access]);`

Comment: $user is an array. You can't access like this `$data->user->name;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `toArray()` method to convert your collections of `User` and `Access` models to arrays, then collect those in a collection:

```
$users = User::all()->toArray();
$access = Access::all()->toArray();

$data = collect(["users" => $users, "access" => $access]);
```